# How to execute java project without the exec plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, maven, execute, launch

I'd like to know other than launching it from a program such as eclipse and other than from using the exec maven plugin, is there any other way to launch a java project?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Java application launcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) which comes packaged with the JDK.  In its most basic form, the command line usage looks like this:

```
java MyMainClass
```

You may find it useful to use the `-cp` flag to set the classpath, and the `-jar` flag to launch the application from a jar file:

```
java -cp C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses -jar myProgram.jar
```

See the documentation for other useful flags.  For more information on the basic Java command line tools, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/#basic.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the options of packaging up all of your classes and resources inside a jar and providing a manifest file.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

That way when you double click the jar, if the file association is set up correctly, it will launch your application.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the maven-assembly-plugin to build a jar-with-dependencies. Then you can typically execute with

```
java -jar my-app-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```